# domain filter for many2one fields in odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

Below code is asset inherited class . Here i will add **'place'** field with **'Karn/Bang/Kengeri'**  and **'karn/bang/malleshwaram'**  for  'Karn/Bang/Kengeri' will add 'asset_catg_id' with A and B. then for 'karn/bang/malleshwaram' with Y and Z.

Now at calander inherited class . if i select **'place'** with **'Karn/Bang/Kengeri'** then next field **'asset_catg_id'** i have to get only **A and B** drop down list. if again **'karn/bang/malleshwaram'** then i have to get only **Y,Z** options . and previous selected **'asset_catg_id'** values should get deleted . i have tried with domain filter option got **keyvalue error**

```
class asset_asset(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "asset.asset"
    #_name = "asset_asset"
    _rec_name= "folio_num"
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Asset Name', size=64),
        'place': fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation', 'Location'),
        'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg', 'Asset Catg Selection', select=True, required=True),}

class asset_catg(osv.Model): 
    _name="asset.catg" 
    _rec_name='name1'
    _description="Define Asset Catgs" 
    _columns={ 'name1':fields.char('Asset Catg Names',size=64,required=True),}
asset_catg()
class asset_parentlocation(osv.osv):
    _name="asset.parentlocation"
    _rec_name="location_name"
    _columns = {
        'location_name' : fields.char('Asset Location', required=True),
        'parent_location' : fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation','Parent Location'),
        'nameee':fields.many2one('ir.attachment','Attachments'),}

    def name_get(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if context is None:
            context = {}
        if not ids:
            return []
        reads = self.read(cr, uid, ids, ['location_name','parent_location'], context=context)
        res = []
        for record in reads:
            name = record['location_name']
            if record['parent_location']:
                name = record['parent_location'][1]+' / '+name
            res.append((record['id'], name))
        return res



**Following code is calendar inherited class** 


class calendar_event(osv.osv):

    _inherit = "calendar.event"
    _rec_name = 'number'

    _columns = {
            'number' : fields.char('Meeting ID',readonly=1),
            #'place' : fields.many2one('stock.location','Substation Location',),

            'place' : fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation','Substation Location',),
            #'location' : fields.selection(STATUS_SELECTION,'Location',  default='Board A'),
            'asset_catg_id' : fields.many2one('asset.catg','Asset Catg Selection', domain="[('asset_catg_id', '=',place)]"),}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First your domain is wrong in a principle. Domain is what is "inside" a field, in other words in its model (for example field `name` or `id` in `asset.catg` model). So you should fix that one first.

If domain depends on another field, you can use onchange method to return domain (used placeholder `place_id`). Like this:

```
@api.onchange('place')
def onchange_place(self):
    res = {}
    if self.place:
        res['domain'] = {'asset_catg_id': [('place_id', '=', self.place.id)]}
    return res
```

**P.S.** This is example with new v8 api, but same principle applies to old api (you then don't nee to use decorator, also add `cr, uid, ids` on method and call it through your view. All of this not needed for new api). As it looks like you are still developing on old api.

**Update** 
For old api:

```
def onchange_place(self,cr, uid, ids, place, context=None):
    res = {}
    if self.place: #on old api it will return id, instead of record
        res['domain'] = {'asset_catg_id': [('place_id', '=', self.place)]}
    return res
```

And then in your view (don't know what kind of view you are using):

```
<field name="place" on_change="onchange_place(place)"/>
```

Still you need to define some field in `asset.catg` so it would be used to match `place` field. For example:

```
'place_id': fields.many2one('asset.parentlocation', 'Place')
```

And then when you define asset category, you set which Place it should belong to. Then when you choose place `calendar.event`, onchange method will set domain on `asset_catg_id` field correctly.

Comment: i am new to odoo please replay me with changes with my code if you dont mind

Comment: I've written you a solution. You should at least give what you did and what did not work. You need to put some work too you know.

Comment: as you said i had done same thing at code but its giving internal server error . i dont know why . i am not getting why ?

Comment: So you should provide an error and all steps you did. I can't help you if you can't show me what you are trying to do.

Comment: i am getting error ''AttributeError: 'calendar.event' object has no attribute '_ids'''

Comment: @Andrius your code snippet help me alot,thanx buddy,but one annoying thing is happen which is the domain filtering is shows the previous value.
For more Details:-I have 2 dropdowns 2nd one is depend on first one so I want to do that when I select the value from first dropdown the 2nd dropdown should populated a/c to the value of first dropdown.It works but 2nd dropdown shows value based on previuos selection (selected on first dropdown list).Thanx in advance :)

Comment: I have similar problem as @MYounus. I made a separate question out of it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369835/dynamic-domain-does-not-work-properly-in-odoo9