# domain filter many2one odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

How to filter many2one fields

```
module1: 
class one_one:
      _name='one.one'
      'f1':fields.char('one')

module2:
class two_two:
     _name="two.two'
     'f1':fields.many2one('one.one','one'),
     'f2':fields.char('two')


module3:
class three_three:
     _name='three.three'
     'f1':fields.many2one('one.one','one'),
     'f2':fields.many2one('two.two','two'),
```

for 
class one_one i will create :1,2,3
class two_two i will create : (1,abc),(2,def),(3,ghi)

I wanted the following way at method 3 i.e class three_three

If i select f1 as '1' the next field f2 i have to get 'abc' only same way for'2','3'. 
I had worked with domain filter but I am getting 'leaf' error please any one reply me for this issue by giving some example

Comment: please edit your question with that error logs and also what you tried.

Comment: whats the you are getting ? post your error...

Comment: this is sample code . this is not my actual code i want domain filter so i possible post on simple code i havve huge code .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112604/domain-filter-for-many2one-fields-in-odoo/31112961?noredirect=1#comment50277044_31112961

Comment: above link has my code no one replied . got one replay with no proper explanation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4964373/usman-maqbool please replay me