# Dynamic domain does not work properly in odoo9

Tags: python, dynamic, dns, onchange, odoo

In Odoo9 I need a dynamic domain that depends on `many2one` field on a wizard.
Using various examples I made it work, but the filtered values are always valid for previous option. Or they are valid if I choose an (invalid) option from the filtered domain.

**Details:**

At the end of opportunity workflow a salesman is supposed to evaluate opportunity where s/he chooses the probability of success. There were several levels to be chosen in special wizard ("100% sure", "not sure", "maybe" etc). I used `fields.Selection` for this. Then I introduced a new opportunity type (retention) where only 100% and 0% should be available. So I created a new model `evaluation_option`, replaced `fields.Selection` with `fields.Many2one` and out of these values I filter out allowed options (with `retention=True`).

This is my wizard model:

```
class evaluation_wizard(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'evaluation.wizard'
    _description = 'Wizard to evaluate opportunity'

    lead_id = fields.Many2one('crm.lead')
    evaluation_option_id = fields.Many2one('evaluation.option')

    def get_object(self, model, fieldname):
        ids = self._context.get(fieldname)
        if ids is None:
            ids = self._context.get('default_' + fieldname)
        return self.env[model].browse(ids)

    @api.onchange('lead_id')
    def _onchange_lead_id(self):
        # I check the context to get lead_id
        lead_id = self.lead_id if self else self.get_object('crm.lead', 'lead_id')
        dom = [('retention', '=', True)] if lead_id.retention else []
        return {'domain': {'evaluation_option_id': dom}}
```

and this is actual wizard

```
    <record id="evaluation_wizard_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">evaluation.wizard.view</field>
        <field name="model">evaluation.wizard</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Evaluate opportunity">
                <sheet class="row">
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="lead_id" invisible="False"/>
                            <field name="evaluation_option_id" required="True"
                                   create="False" edit="False" widget="radio"
                            />
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <footer>
                        <button name="evaluate"
                                type="object"
                                string="Confirm"
                                class="oe_highlight"
                                context="{'lead_id': default_lead_id,
                                          'active_id': default_lead_id,
                                          'evaluation_option_id': evaluation_option_id}"/>
                    </footer>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

I made an onchange method for dynamic changing of the domain, shown above. I tried also to compute domain like this:  `evaluation_option_id = fields.Many2one('evaluation.option', domain=_compute_domain)` where `compute_domain` was the same method as for onchange but decorated with `api.depends`. None of the methods worked as expected.

I use transient model with values (e.g. `lead_id`) prefilled with default values (`default_lead_id`) via context on button.

Whatever I try, when I make domain actually work it filters out the values, but always valid for previous selection. It means if I choose a retention opportunity I get all the options, if I then choose normal opportunity I get the retention options. If the next one is regular opportunity, the options are correct. However, if I choose retention opportunity (and invalid options are shown) and then I pick an invalid option, the invalid options would filter out suddenly. I am not sure, but it seems to me that the same problem is referred here: [domain filter for many2one fields in odoo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31112604/domain-filter-for-many2one-fields-in-odoo#31112961) in the last comment of accepted answer.

Can you see an obvious mistake or do you know another way how to dynamically change domain?

--
Edit:

I eventually managed to make it work. I do not remember what exactly I have done a year ago but the comparison between the old version and current version of code shows this:

1) I updated get_object method to get lead_id directly from the form and then if not successful, try dig it from the context.

```
def get_object(self, model, fieldname):
    value = getattr(self, fieldname, None)
    if value is not None:
        return value
    ids = self._context.get(fieldname, None)
    if ids is None:
        ids = self._context.get('default_' + fieldname)
    ids = [] if ids is None else ids
    return self.env[model].browse(ids)


@api.onchange('lead_id')
def _onchange_lead_id(self):
    lead_id = self.get_object('crm.lead', 'lead_id')
    dom = [('retention', '=', True)] if lead_id.is_retention_opp else []
    return {'domain': {'evaluation_option_id': dom}}
```

2) the other change is in xml - readonly `lead_id` (so that it is only called once when rendering the wizard) and removed radio widget from `evaluation_option_id`:

```
<group>
    <field name="lead_id" invisible="True" readonly="True"/>
    <field name="evaluation_option_id" required="True"
           options="{'no_create': True}"/>
</group>
```

Hopefully this might help someone.

Comment: Hi, please tell me if you has a answer, I have the same problem.

Comment: @GabrielAsqui at the moment it seems it works correctly. Honestly, I don't know what actually worked for me as it is already a year old issue. However, I compared submitted code with the current version and I think that only relevant difference is that I made the `lead_id` invisible& readonly (so the onchange is called when rendering a wizard) and removed radio widget from the second field. I put my changes below the original question.